# Ayuda con la impresión de Nodos de pila en textArea

Tags: java, netbeans

Tengo un programa que se encarga de hacer traslados de Pila a Lista, Cola, Lista simple, etc.
El problema es que no sé cómo mostrar el resultado en el `TextArea`, por ejemplo, al pasar de pila a arreglo, no me deja mostrar el arreglo porque se halla en otro método. Y el método imprimir que tengo es del tipo void así que mucho no puede hacer... La impresión se tiene que hacer despúes de aplastar un botón que pasa la pila al arreglo.

```
public class MenuPila extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form Menu
 */
public MenuPila() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    pilaarreglo = new javax.swing.JButton();
    pilasimple = new javax.swing.JButton();
    pilacircular = new javax.swing.JButton();
    pilacola = new javax.swing.JButton();
    pilalistade = new javax.swing.JButton();
    textopila = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    textotraslado = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    regresarpila = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 3, 13)); // NOI18N
    jLabel1.setText("Se realizará un traslado desde una Pila a:");

    pilaarreglo.setText("Arreglo");
    pilaarreglo.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            pilaarregloActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    pilasimple.setText("Lista Simple");

    pilacircular.setText("Lista Circular");

    pilacola.setText("Cola");

    pilalistade.setText("Lista Doblemente Enlazada");

    textopila.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            textopilaActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel2.setText("Pila original");

    jLabel3.setText("Traslado");

    regresarpila.setText("REGRESAR");
    regresarpila.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            regresarpilaActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(58, 58, 58)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(pilalistade)
                        .addComponent(pilacola)
                        .addComponent(pilacircular)
                        .addComponent(pilasimple)
                        .addComponent(pilaarreglo))
                    .addGap(99, 99, 99)
                    .addComponent(textopila, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 138, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)


    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addComponent(textotraslado, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 119, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addContainerGap(29, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel1)
                        .addGap(73, 73, 73)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel3)
                        .addGap(74, 74, 74))))
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(regresarpila)
                .addGap(270, 270, 270))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(30, 30, 30)
                            .addComponent(jLabel1))
                        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addContainerGap()
                            .addComponent(jLabel2)))
                    .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(pilaarreglo)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(pilasimple)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addComponent(pilacircular)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(pilacola)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(pilalistade))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(1, 1, 1)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(textotraslado)
                            .addComponent(textopila))))
                .addGap(50, 50, 50)
                .addComponent(regresarpila)
                .addContainerGap(51, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    public void mostrarmenu() {
        Interfaz i = new Interfaz();
        i.setVisible(true);
        i.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
    private void regresarpilaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        mostrarmenu();
        this.setVisible(false);

    }
    Traslados t = new Traslados();
    Nodo n = new Nodo();
    private void pilaarregloActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

        n = t.insercionInicioListaDE(n);
        int[] arreglo = t.pilaArreglo(n);
        textopila.setText("");


    }

    private void textopilaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            textopila.setText(arreglo); //Aquí me sale error porque no encuentra la variable arreglo

    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MenuPila.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MenuPila.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MenuPila.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MenuPila.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new MenuPila().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JButton pilaarreglo;
    private javax.swing.JButton pilacircular;
    private javax.swing.JButton pilacola;
    private javax.swing.JButton pilalistade;
    private javax.swing.JButton pilasimple;
    private javax.swing.JButton regresarpila;
    private javax.swing.JTextField textopila;
    private javax.swing.JTextField textotraslado;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

El código que genera el arreglo desde la pila:

```
public int[] pilaArreglo(Nodo pila) {
    Nodo temp2 = pila;
    int n = 0;
    while (temp2 != null) {
        n = n + 1;
        temp2 = temp2.sig;
    }
    int arreglo[] = new int[n];
    temp2 = pila;
    System.out.println("El arreglo generado a partir de la pila es: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        arreglo[i] = temp2.num;
        System.out.println(arreglo[i] + "");
        temp2 = temp2.sig;
    }
    System.out.println("");
    return arreglo;
}
```

Y el código que genera la pila original que también debo mostrar en otro textArea:

```
 static class Nodo {

    int num;
    Nodo ant;
    Nodo sig;
}


  //Método que permite crear una pila de multiplos de 3
public Nodo insercionInicioPila(Nodo top) {

    top = null;
    int n = 10; //Se generan 10 numeros en la pila
    int m = 3; //Multiplos de 3
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        Nodo temp = new Nodo();
        temp.num = i * m;
        if (top == null) {
            temp.sig = null;
        } else {
            temp.sig = top;
        }
        top = temp;
    }
    return top;
}
```

Y este es mi método imprimir:

```
 //Metodo para imprimir la estructura de datos necesitada
public void imprimir(Nodo top) {
    Nodo temp1 = top;
    while (temp1 != null) {
        System.out.println(temp1.num + "");
        temp1 = temp1.sig;
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

El error lo estás teniendo porque la variable `arreglo` la declaraste dentro del ámbito del método `pilaarregloActionPerformed()` (el ámbito lo determinan los caracteres {...}, los tres puntos representan todo el código que se encuentra dentro del ámbito). Para solucionar esto, simplemente declara la variable `arreglo` debajo de la declaración de las variables `t` y `n`:

```
Traslados t = new Traslados();
Nodo n = new Nodo();
int[] arreglo = null;
private void pilaarregloActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    n = t.insercionInicioListaDE(n);
    arreglo = t.pilaArreglo(n);
    textopila.setText("");
}
```

Ahora bien, esta línea de código, `textopila.setText(arreglo);`, no te va a mostrar el contenido del arreglo dentro del campo de texto, te mostraría algo como esto `[I@1a06f956`. Para hacerlo debes recorrer el arreglo, como haces en el método imprimir, e ir concatenando el valor de cada posición a un ´String´, o mejor, utilizando un `StringBuilder`. Por ejemplo, puedes crearte un método que a partir de un arreglo puedas obtener una cadena de texto con los valores de cada posición separados por coma:

```
public String arrayToString(int[] arr) {
    if (arr == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("'arr' no puede ser null");

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        int item = arr[i];
        if (i == 0)
            builder.append(item);
        else
            builder.append(", ").append(item);
    }

    return builder.toString();
}
```

Entonces cambiar esta línea `textopila.setText(arreglo);` por esta otra `textopila.setText(arrayToString(arreglo));`.

Espero poder ayudarte.

Un saludo